# Angular 7 reactive forms binding intercepting

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-directives, angular-directive

I want to format data (provided by user )to my own format or change them on the fly (eg. set 0 when user put a value lower than 0 or something like that). I mostly use a reactive forms solution to connect view with code behind. What I've done it by intercepting my binding between the variable of FormControl type and the control on the view thanks to a directive. I would like to stay with this but the problem is that the directive isn't real interceptor as a value change event occurs with wrong value and then is formatted by directive function (the change event is called second time). This is how I achieved that:

```
@HostListener("blur", ["$event.target.value"])onBlur(event: any) {
    let value = this.transformValue(event);
    this.control.setValue(value, { emitEvent: false });
    this.el.value = value;
}
```

Is there a way to achieve the real interception behaviour through directives?

**EDIT:**
I've created a simple sample of my case. Please, take a look. What I want to achieve is only one (second) change event call.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ctnjup

Comment: Could you check please what is called first? Your directive handler or your data change handler?

Comment: Hi, definately data change handler is being called first. Take a look at my stackblitz's sample (look at the edited part of the post).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, **directive won't help** you here, but, you can use that fact that `valueChanges` is `Observable` and make a **clean and nice solution** based on that. Basically you can use **map + tap operators** to map your changes and set them back to input **before subscription**. Example:

```
this.sub$ = this.formControl.valueChanges.pipe(
  map(x => x === "" ? 0 : parseFloat(x) || 0),
  tap(x => this.formControl.setValue(x, {emitEvent: false}))
).subscribe(x => {
  console.log("change: " + x);
  this.changes.push(x);
});
```

Working [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-geb9wf?file=src/app/sample/sample.component.ts). Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Jaume, in the constructor of a directive you can inject the ElementName and the control itself if the directive is applied to a input control

```
constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef,private control:NgControl) {
   //this.control was the control itself
}
```

So, you can add HotListener ove input, over focus,over blur...

```
@HostListener("blur", ["$event.target.value"])onBlur(event: any) {
    let value = this.transformValue(event);
    this.control.setValue(value, { emitEvent: false });
    this.el.value = value;
}
```

Comment: Hello, take a look at the link in the edited part of the post. I'm doing exactly how you described.